# How to use collections or joins in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, collection, join

I'm trying to filter by `order_item` to get a list of orders.

Get all orders where an order item has a price greater than 5.

How would this be done? Collections? Joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to filter order collection based on order item price

```
    protected $_resourceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $resourceFactory,
        ....
    ) {
        $this->_resourceFactory = $resourceFactory;
    }


    public function yourfunction(){
        $collection = $this->_resourceFactory->create();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                   ['order'=>$collection->getTable('sales_order')],
                   'main_table.order_id = order.entity_id',
                   ['order_status'=>'order.status','base_shipping_amount'=>'order.base_shipping_amount']);
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('price',array('gt' => 5));

        return $collection;
    }
```